# sort Folder names from directory Using PHP

Tags: php, sorting

Hii Everyone,

```
        Here I get all files from folder and sort names using PHP.


<?php 
$dir = "Car_Brands";
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    $files[] = $filename;
}
sort($files);
print_r($files);
?>
```

It Gives Result in Order of

```
    Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => ALTO [3] => BEAT [4] => CRUZE [5] => Civic mugen kit [6] => Civic type R kit [7] => Ertiga [8] => FIESTA [9] => FIGO [10] => I20 [11] => LANCER [12] => LINEA [13] => MANZA [14] => NEW I20 [15] => New Beat [16] => New Figo [17] => POLO [18] => SWIFT [19] => SX4 [20] => VENTO [21] => VERNA [22] => VISTA [23] => accord car modification [24] => civic customized kit [25] => hondacity [26] => hondacity 2nd generation [27] => hondacity 3rd generation [28] => octavia [29] => rapid )
```

But I want Order in ALTO and Accord should in first.If the words having space It moves last in alphabetical order Why is it so.How can I recover this Problem.Please anyone give me the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are moving to last not because of space. its because of `sort` case sensitive.

Try [natcasesort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php)

```
natcasesort($files);
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

use [natsort()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_natsort.asp) instead of sort

For your code it would be:

```
<?php 
$dir = "Car_Brands";
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
    $files[] = $filename;
}
natsort($files);
print_r($files);
?>
```